# Kotlin: Printing string with array elements that cuts off left side of answers

Tags: kotlin, string-interpolation

I am writing a small text based game to familiarize myself with Kotlin. I am creating two strings that print out the multiple choice options. I have confirmed that all four array elements are captured appropriately, but when the string prints it cuts off the a) and c) options. I have used \t, spaces, etc. and it does the same thing. I have also tried to just use print() and then use a \n at the end

```
println(menuList[0])
println(menuList[1])
println(menuList[2])
println(menuList[3])

println("a) ${menuList[0]} b) ${menuList[1]}")
println("c) ${menuList[2]} d) ${menuList[3]}")
```

Output:

[erroneous output of multiple choice text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6QJt.png)

Comment: Seems to work fine when I try it. How are you constructing your array? What environment are you running it in? And can you replicate it here: https://try.kotlinlang.org/ ?

Comment: I am loading it from a text file, and am using IntelliJ. The code below is how I import it into the menuList. It does work when I put it in try.kotlinlang.org. So strange as to why it won't print correctly in my console.

    val menuList = File("data/balltypes.txt")
            .readText()
            .split("\n")
            .shuffled()

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with the splitting by the new line character. Are you on Windows? If so, the new-line is `\r\n` normally, not `\n`. So try splitting by `\r\n` instead and see if that helps. If not, try calling `trim` on each item in the `List` returned from the `shuffled` method.

Comment: The \r\n fixed it! Wow, thank you so much. Is there a way to upvote your comment or profile, this is my first question on stack overflow.

Comment: Just as a side note, on your next question, please avoid inserting output on images, rather, insert it directly via formatted text

Comment: @DOwens, normally how it works is someone posts an answer (rather than comments as we've been doing) and you mark the answer as correct. In this case we weren't sure what the issue was so were using comments to track down the issue. I'll now post an answer, then you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The source text came from a file which was separating each line with `\r\n`, but the code reading it was splitting it with `\n`. The result was that each entry ended with `\r`. When printed out, this caused the first value to be overwritten.

The solution is, when reading the file, to split by `\r\n` rather than `\n`.